# List changer function

Tags: list

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out a simple Prolog issue here. 
I need to perform some sort of manipulation (defined by myself) on the elements of a list of atoms. However, I should only perform such a manipulation if the element in question of the list returns true for a specified predicate P(x).

So basically, if I have the rule:

```
mutate_if(isOdd, addOne, [1,2,3,4,5], L2).
```

I should get the following output:

```
L2 = [2,2,4,4,6]
```

I've come up with this code so far

```
mutate_if(P, OP, L1, L2):-
  findall(Y, ((member(X,L1),
  Oper=.. [P,X],
  call(Oper)) -> (Mutate=.. [OP, X, Y], call(Mutate)); X=Y),
  L2).
```

In my head, this should work well, however when I run this on Prolog-SWI, I get the following:

```
?- mutate_if(isOdd, addOne, [1,2,3,4,5], L2).<
L2=[2].
```

where `isOdd` and `addOne` are both simple rules which check to see if the input variable is odd, and add one to the input variable, respectively.

I can't figure out why Prolog is only finding one element of the list when the `findall` predicate should technically be finding all the members of the first list.

Is this a fault in my own logic?

Answer (score 2):

A couple of suggestions...

You don't need `=../2` for this. `call(P, X)` will call the functor `P` with argument `X`, and `call(OP, X, Y)` will call functor `OP` with arguments `X` and `Y`.

You can use `findall` here if you set your condition correctly. It will collect the values that result in the given expression succeeding (yielding `true`). Since you want to *map* each element of the list to a result, I would use `maplist/3` with a predicate like, `mutate_one_if(P, OP, X, Y)` which mutates a single `X` to `Y` or leaves it alone (`X = Y`) depending upon the condition (as you are requiring).

```
mutate_one_if(P, OP, X, Y) :-
    (   call(P, X)
    ->  call(OP, X, Y)
    ;   X = Y
    ).

mutate_if(P, OP, L1, L2) :-
    maplist(mutate_one_if(P, OP), L1, L2).
```

`maplist/3` will call `mutate_one_if(P, OP)` for each corresponding element from `L1` and `L2`. As you can see, `call` is very flexible, since if you want to call `mutate_one_if(P, OP, X, Y)`, you can call it as, `call(mutate_one_if(P, OP), X, Y)` or as `call(mutate_one_if(P, OP, X, Y))`. Prolog's `call` will gather the arguments appropriately.

So, using these:

```
isOdd(X) :- X /\ 1 =:= 1.
addOne(X, Y) := Y is X + 1.
```

Yields:

```
| ?- mutate_if(isOdd, addOne, [1,2,3,4,5], L).

L = [2,2,4,4,6]

yes
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're not properly *scoping* the 'if/then/else' operands.
With this definition

```
mutate_if(P, OP, L1, L2):-
  findall(Y, (
    member(X,L1),
    Oper=.. [P,X],
    ( call(Oper) -> Mutate=.. [OP, X, Y], call(Mutate); X=Y )
  ), L2).
```

I get

```
?- mutate_if(isOdd, addOne, [1,2,3,4,5], L).
L = [2, 2, 4, 4, 6].
```

(p.s. note that @lurker suggestions are very valuable)